# RTS Game Design and Code Organization

Tags: c#, xna, code-formatting

I would like to write a 2D real time strategy game probably using XNA and was looking for a book or other resource that walks through the structure of the code and the main process of creating a larger game.

Does anyone know of any good resources I can use.

Comment: You might get a better response posting this question at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: You might [get better answers here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Secondly: Read this [old article](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3094/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php) that still contains a lot of valuable information on a classic RTS game. [www.Gamasutra.com](http://www.Gamasutra.com) is a very valuable source of information.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml might be helpfull.

If you havent done any XNA game development before I would start with the simple stuff and work your way through the tutorials before getting into writing your game.